# How can I switch back to an application without Launcher and alt+tab?

Tags: unity, launcher

So, normally when I run eclipse it is shown in both alt+tab and unity launcher. Now I have a running eclipse, I  minimised it and I can't switch to eclipse any more.

Is there other way to switch back to an application without using unity launcher or alt+tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing Super+W spreads all the windows out, so you might find it there.[image: screenshot]

If you don't, you can launch gnome-panel from the terminal (if it's installed) to get a GNOME 2 style taskbar, also seen in the screenshot above.